# How to get the subnet id for existing vpc subnet in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I want to create a subnetgroup for redshift cluster: this template I found:

```
RedshiftClusterSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::Redshift::ClusterSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Cluster subnet group
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB
```

Lets say I have two already existed subnet names are: subnetA and subnet B
How to use that if I dont want to create the subnet from template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types):

```
Parameters:
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
```

This way you can easily choose the existing subnets for your `RedshiftClusterSubnetGroup`.